# TextBox onkeypress event disappears

Tags: asp.net, textbox, onkeypress

I have a very strange story ...
My asp page:

```
...
<asp:TextBox id="empNum" runat="server" onblur="empNum_onblur()" onkeypress="empNum_onkeypress()"></asp:TextBox>
...
```

In view source, in browser:

```
...
<input id="empNum" runat="server" onblur="empNum_onblur()" />
...
```

Where is onkeypress event ???

Answer (score 0):

Add runat="server" in your form.

Comment: I tried the same code and its working for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE. Did you try adding the events in document.ready ?

Comment: yes. I solved it in this way, but where onkeypress ? :)
I can't publish full source, because it on network not connected to internet

Comment: what you meant by "but where onkeypress ? "